# What information that is on a bootable clone is omitted from a non-bootable clone?

Tags: backup, restore, migration

I understand that a bootable clone can be used in different scenarios from a non-bootable one, but I'm not clear on what information — specifically what customizations I've made over the years to my system — is present on a bootable clone but not present on a non-bootable one.

For years I've used a bootable clone to support scenarios like needing immediate access to my full machine will traveling, even if my MacBook dies, or still being able to get up and running, even if my internal drive is damaged. But now I'm simply mostly interested in being able to migrate to a new machine when the time comes. Since non-bootable clones are easier to make (e.g. making a bootable clone for Big Sur can be problematic), I wonder if I can get by with one. But it's not clear to me if a non-bootable clone will have *all* of the information I'm accustomed to.

What information — specifically what settings, customizations, or configurations — is present on a bootable clone, but not on a non-bootable one?

Comment: Explain the downvotes please.

Comment: So, I didn't downvote, but I feel that your question needs clarification on several aspects: First, you should define precisely what you mean by a "clone" here. A disk image created with dd or another tool? That's not clear to me. Also, I am not certain what the concept of bootable/non-bootable would entail in this scenario (see the comments below). Finally, describe the process you attempt to create a "bootable clone" with, and why you consider it problematic for Big Sur.

Answer (score -1):

The [UEFI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unified_Extensible_Firmware_Interface) partition contents or [Boot Sector](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boot_sector) contents are what make a drive bootable with some possible caveats, eg. the machine must be able to boot from a properly configured device that has been connected the same way as your non-bootable clone.

I can't confirm if anything else might be missing without more detail on your cloning process.

Comment: Isn't a clone a clone? How would the process result in something meaningfully different? In any case: CCC is being used to make the clones (bootable or not).

Comment: And to be clear: The question is not about what makes the clone bootable. It's about whether any information other than the ability to boot differs.

Comment: > Isn't a clone a clone?: If your cloning methods give varying results of bootability it seems fairly self evident that this isn’t the case. 
> And to be clear: The question is not about what makes the clone bootable. It's about whether any information other than the ability to boot differs: The contents of the UEFI partition and boot sector contain information about the boot process. You’ll have to be more specific if that isn’t what you mean.

Comment: Scottmeup: There is no boot sector. The [document **you referenced**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unified_Extensible_Firmware_Interface) even states this: *"Unlike the legacy PC BIOS, UEFI does not rely on boot sectors, defining instead a boot manager as part of the UEFI specification."* Another problem with your answer is that Macs do not follow the UEFI specification with respect to booting. In other words, the software to boot macOS does not reside in an EFI partition as required by the UEFI specification.

Comment: @DavidAnderson The question as stated is "What information that is on a bootable clone is omitted from a non-bootable clone?". Lacking further information on the specifications of exactly what OP is backing up, it's not safe to assume that it doesn't have BIOS / boot sector.

Comment: @Scottmeup: You may have a point. While the OP does mention Big Sur, the OP does not actually state the clone is of macOS or OS X.